# ASP.NET Web API retunrs Internal Server 500 error while accessing through xamarin Mobile Application.?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, xamarin.forms

I wrote asp.net web api and accessing same from xamarin forms mobile app.But while accessing web api i am getting Internal server error 500.

Web API Code:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("getObjectName")]
public ActionResult<List<string>> getObjectName([FromBody]imageData data)
{
Console.WriteLine("base64`enter code here`:" + data.imageBase64);
            var detectionResult= objectDetection.detectImage(data.imageBase64);

            if(detectionResult==null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return detectionResult;
        }
```

Xamarin Forms Code:

```
var url =new Uri( "https://tensorflowapi.azurewebsites.net/api/v1/getObjectName");
           // string url = "https://10.0.3.2:5001/api/v1/getObjectName";
            HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
            imageData data = new imageData { imageBase64 = "values" };
            var content =new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data),Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            var apiResult =await httpClient.PostAsync(url, content);

            var result=await apiResult.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Comment: Debug your API while you test. It will show you the line that throws the exception and why.

Comment: Also use Postman or a similar tool to make a request so that you can see if you lack anything like a Header and when in the tool it gives you a 200 you can compare with your code to see what's missing

Comment: @fmaccaroni  tried with Postman in Localhost that time it is working fine but when it comes to hosted web api then it's giving me 500 internal Server Error.

Comment: @GabrielLuci can you please tell me how to debug web api in xamarin forms application.